# Fastest way to write a FloatBuffer or Float(float) array to a file in Java

Tags: java, file, floating-point, buffer, filechannel

I've got a bunch of float data in a `FloatBuffer` which needs to be written to a file (without it taking three minutes). Currently a `DataOutputStream` is used to write the `FloatBuffer` element by element to a file. This is slow. Preferably, I'd like to be using a `FileChannel`, but I hit a snag since it seems a `FloatBuffer` can't be converted to a `ByteBuffer` and bytes are what the `FileChannel` needs in order to write data.

Instead of using `FoatBuffers` as my data source, I could easily be using an array. But I can't easily use a ByteBuffer/array instead.

Any insight into this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of starting *off* with a `FloatBuffer`, could you create a `ByteBuffer` to use for writing to the `FileChannel`, then use `ByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer`, write into that `FloatBuffer` however you're currently doing it, and then write out the `ByteBuffer` which will then contain the relevant information?

Personally I've always found java.nio rather confusing, but this feels like it probably *should* work...

EDIT: Another user tried this, and found it not to work:

> However, `asFloatBuffer()` will not work because `hasArray()` will be false. In short, the following does not work (neither `allocate`, nor `allocateDirect` will work):
>
> ```
> ByteBuffer.allocate(amount * 4).asFloatBuffer().asArray()
> ```

I don't have the time to investigate alternatives right now, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, I forgot the ByteBuffer had a putFloat function. This works really well. Using a FileChannel is so very much faster. Thanks.

Comment: @user756670: It has putFloat, but that's a single-shot operation. Using `asFloatBuffer` allows you to do bulk putting, which is probably better yet.

Comment: I have an external library that returns FloatBuffer object, so I cannot start with ByteBuffer. What do I do?

Comment: @AlexPetrenko: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492161/convert-floatbuffer-to-bytebuffer

Comment: I have no such method on my FloatBuffer. There are no methods that return ByteBuffer, I checked) I use Android.

Comment: @AlexPetrenko: I edited my comment very shortly after writing it - did you check the referenced question? I suggest you ask a new question with more details - in particular that it's for Android - if that doesn't help you.