# Convert FloatBuffer to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

`ByteBuffer` offers `asFloatBuffer()` function. However, there is no equivalent `FloatBuffer.asByteBuffer()`

I am trying to do:

```
float[] array = ...
try( ByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel( path, WRITE, CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING ) ) {
    channel.write (FloatBuffer.wrap (array) .asByteBuffer());
}
```

Is there a way of efficiently doing this, or do I have to resort to allocating a `ByteBuffer` as in:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( array.length * 4 );
buffer .asFloatBuffer() .put (array);
channel.write (buffer);
```

Comment: Does this answer suit to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298997/convert-from-floatbuffer-to-byte

Comment: @ServerSideCat He is already doing what that answers says to do.

Comment: You are correct. There is no other way to do it.

Comment: I actually wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how to do this seemingly simple task. Being a C programmer, I was pretty shocked to realize there's no easy way to do it without a for loop. The only alternative I found was starting with a `ByteBuffer`, and then creating my array (e.g. float[]) as a view into the `ByteBuffer`, e.g. `bb.asFloatBuffer`. That's the price you pay for abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `HeapFloatBuffer`, ie created by `FloatBuffer.allocate` or `FloatBuffer.wrap`, there is no easy solution. A custom class extending ByteBuffer needs to be written.

For direct buffers in HotSpot 8, this will work in the trivial case:

```
FloatBuffer floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect (...).asFloatBuffer();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) ((sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer)floatBuffer).attachment();
```

For other situations, use the following. Note that this class is declared in package `java.nio`. This also probably will only work in HotSpot 8.

```
package java.nio;

/**
 *
 * @author Aleksandr Dubinsky
 */
public class BufferUtils {

      public static ByteBuffer
    asByteBuffer (FloatBuffer floatBuffer) {

            if (floatBuffer instanceof DirectFloatBufferU)
            {
                DirectFloatBufferU buffer = (DirectFloatBufferU) floatBuffer;
                return (ByteBuffer) new DirectByteBuffer (buffer.address(), floatBuffer.capacity() * Float.BYTES, buffer)
                                            .position (floatBuffer.position() * Float.BYTES)
                                            .limit (floatBuffer.limit() * Float.BYTES);
            }
            else if (floatBuffer instanceof DirectFloatBufferS)
            {
                DirectFloatBufferS buffer = (DirectFloatBufferS) floatBuffer;
                return (ByteBuffer) new DirectByteBuffer (buffer.address(), floatBuffer.capacity() * Float.BYTES, buffer)
                                            .position (floatBuffer.position() * Float.BYTES)
                                            .limit (floatBuffer.limit() * Float.BYTES);
            }
            else if (floatBuffer instanceof ByteBufferAsFloatBufferB)
            {
                ByteBufferAsFloatBufferB buffer = (ByteBufferAsFloatBufferB)floatBuffer;
                return (ByteBuffer) ((ByteBuffer) buffer.bb
                                                        .duplicate()
                                                        .position (buffer.offset)
                                                        .limit (buffer.offset + buffer.capacity() * Float.BYTES))
                                                        .slice()
                                                        .position (buffer.position() * Float.SIZE)
                                                        .limit (buffer.limit() * Float.BYTES);
            }
            else if (floatBuffer instanceof ByteBufferAsFloatBufferL)
            {
                ByteBufferAsFloatBufferL buffer = (ByteBufferAsFloatBufferL)floatBuffer;
                return (ByteBuffer) ((ByteBuffer) buffer.bb
                                                        .duplicate()
                                                        .position (buffer.offset)
                                                        .limit (buffer.offset + buffer.capacity() * Float.BYTES))
                                                        .slice()
                                                        .position (buffer.position() * Float.SIZE)
                                                        .limit (buffer.limit() * Float.BYTES);
            }
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Unsupported implementing class " + floatBuffer.getClass().getName());
        }

}
```

Comment: hm, since FloatBuffer is only a view and when you can create the BB first, you could use  `ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer,allocate(); FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();`, they share the same backing.

Comment: @eckes The question assumes you've lost the reference to the original ByteBuffer.